# Displaying the current Year inside my SharePoint master page

Tags: html, css, layout, footer, sharepoint-designer

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 team site. and inside my seatle.master page i have defined the following :-

```
<div id="customFooter"  class="noindex">&copy; .. Group 2013</div>
```

But i am not sure if there is a way to access the Date object from my master page, and then to display the current year instead of manully typing the year. which will require to update the year later on.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
<div id="customFooter" class="noindex">
     &copy; .. Group <%=DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() %>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but this raised the following error. "Sorry, something went wrong 
An error occurred during the processing of /discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom.master. Code blocks are not allowed in this file."

Comment: Have a look at these links on enabling code blocks. http://blog.bullseyeconsulting.com/archive/2013/03/21/fixing-code-blocks-not-allowed.aspx    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120190/How-to-enable-code-blocks-in-Sharepoint-2010-Works

Comment: but using PageParserPath will cause performance problems !! http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2659203

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`<div id="customFooter"  class="noindex">
  &copy; .. Group <script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>
</div>`

Comment: Add some more details to your suggestion to make it a great answer